# Running a function from a web worker

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I have a JS object that has a function which takes another object and an int:

```
this.foo.func(bar, int);
```

Is there a way to pass this function (and/or object) to a worker so it can execute it? Or somehow share the scope with the worker?

I'm not sure but I think Transferable Objects won't help me here since none of the objects can be translated to JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A worker cannot run functions that affect the DOM.

You can only (right now) pass strings to a webworker.

---

What you can do is pass as much information as you can that the webworker can use, and then return what you did to the main window.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with **vkThread** plugin.

It looks like this:

```
function foo(n, m) {
    return n+m;
}

vkthread.exec(foo,     // function to execute in a web worker
              [1, 2],  // arguments for the function
              function(data){ // callback
                             console.log(data); // 3
                           }
);
```

see details at:  http://www.eslinstructor.net/vkthread/